# How check if directory already added to ZipArchive during creation?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Usually, to check for a directory, you would use `$zipArchive->locateName( "dirName" );` but while the zipfile is being created, this does not work. Is there a way to check the zip file during creation for directories?

Does not work:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open( $path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE );

//Returns false even if already created
if ( $this->locateName( $directory ) === false ) ...
```

`$this->statName(...)` also returns false;

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and found that adding a slash to the end of the directory name worked.

```
$zip->addEmptyDir("directoryName");
$zip->locateName("directoryName");  // Returns false
$zip->locateName("directoryName/"); // Returns the location as expected
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works when you manually add the empty directory manually. So this does not work when you add a file in a diretory without creating the directory first.